# formatting txt file in new file and re arranging the data

Tags: python

How to insert 10 spaces in front of data.txt arrange like this

```
  0.00E+00  0.00E+00
  1.00E-02  1.91E-10
  2.00E-02  5.97E-10
  3.01E-02  2.80E-10
  4.01E-02  2.58E-10
```

I have used this code from python programmer post

```py
with  open("data.txt", "r") as rf:
     with  open("data_copy3.txt", "w") as wf:
          for line in rf:
               wf.write(line)
```

I tried `{:>10}` but couldn't insert the space into the new data_copy3.txt

The new file should be arranged like:

```
          0.00E+00  0.00E+00
          1.00E-02  1.91E-10
          2.00E-02  5.97E-10
          3.01E-02  2.80E-10
          4.01E-02  2.58E-10
```

The original file is in the same format, just without 10 spaces in the beginning of each line.

Comment: When asking a coding question, the **very first** tag you should add is one for the language you're using. Please [edit] to add  that tag. The rest of them you added are meaningless.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do this in a text editor?  And you'll find that `' '*10 + line` will create a 10-space leader.

Comment: Do you *actually* want to insert 10 spaces on every line? Or are you trying to create a right-aligned first column of constant width? Are all the first values on each line always 8 characters long, like `2.00E-02`  is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print whatever you want in the loop, e.g.:

```py
with open("data.txt", "r") as rf:
     with open("data_copy3.txt", "w") as wf:
          for line in rf:
               wf.write("         " + line)
```